# Nvidia proprietary drivers 20.04.1 fail with dependency problems

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04, dpkg

I tried first updating my proprietary drivers via the terminal, and after that it failed. Same error after a purge of all NVIDIA packages and reinstall. Don't know how to resolve it. Running Ubuntu 20.04.1 on amd64 arch. I have two pastes:
Failed terminal output for: `sudo apt install nvidia-dkms-450`
See line 30 of the paste above for referenc in the next command.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bQsGwr7ZMN/
Output of `cat /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/450.66/build/make.log` mentioned in above output, line 30:
[https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Nj5WpPm3cj//](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Nj5WpPm3cj/)
I've tried removing the Proprietary Graphics Drivers PPA and just installing via

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Nothing seems to work to get it back to expected behavior, including

```
sudo apt install -f
```

nor

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

So I'm stuck in a difficult place without those drivers. I did email the launchpad team in case it's not just my config but a bug. I tried installing on an updated 20.04.1 USB drive and there were no issues. I want to avoid a reformat because that would be a major pain. Any help is appreciated. Thanks guys for your help in advance!

**Update:**
I solved it by changing my default compiler back to GCC from clang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to make sure via galternatives or update-alternatives is that gcc, not clang is set as default for all schemes it handles.

Comment: How, exactly, did you change the default compiler to gcc?